# How to remove empty space when visibility is set to GONE

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've set the visibility of `RecyclerView` to gone. How would I be able to remove the empty space it takes?

I tried putting `layout_height` as `wrap_content`, but it still doesn't show anything.

**Recycler View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleView"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Card View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:backgroundTint="#5A10E7"
    android:elevation="90dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.282">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Requestfulfilled"
            android:layout_width="139dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"
            android:hint="Request Fullfilled"
            android:text="Fulfilled"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/DeleteRequest"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/RlocationView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RlocationView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/DeleteRequest"
            android:layout_width="139dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"
            android:hint="Delete"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/RlocationView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.894"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.904" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RemailView"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:allowUndo="true"
            android:focusable="auto"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RdateView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RbloodView"
            android:layout_width="116dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:allowUndo="true"
            android:focusable="auto"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Blood Group"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RlocationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/RdateView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RemailView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RdateView"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:allowUndo="true"
            android:focusable="auto"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Date of Requirement"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RlocationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/RbloodView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RemailView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/RlocationView"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:allowUndo="true"
            android:focusable="auto"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Requestfulfilled"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RdateView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Code to set Card visibility as GONE:**

```
   public class yourRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView cardView;

    private DatabaseReference dbRefForReq, dbRefForResp;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String AuthUserEmail, UserID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.request_response_view);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        AuthUserEmail = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

        UserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        dbRefForResp = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Responses").child(String.valueOf(UserID));

        dbRefForReq = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blood Requests");
        dbRefForReq.keepSynced(true);

        cardView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        cardView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        cardView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<getDbContents> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<getDbContents>()
                        .setQuery(dbRefForReq, getDbContents.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<getDbContents, contentHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<getDbContents, contentHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final contentHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final getDbContents model) {
                final int finalPosition = position + 1;
                if (model.getUser().equals(AuthUserEmail)) {
                    dbRefForReq.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            DataSnapshot checkFulfillment = dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(("Request " + finalPosition))).child("Fulfillment");
                            if (checkFulfillment.exists()) {
                                if (checkFulfillment.child("Fulfilled").getValue().equals("yes")) {
                                    /*------------- Set current user card as visible -----------------*/
                                    holder.frameView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.fulfilled.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    holder.requestFulfilled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.userEmail.setText(AuthUserEmail);
                                    holder.bloodGroup.setText(model.getBloodGroup());
                                    holder.dateOfRequirement.setText(model.getDate());
                                    holder.Location.setText(model.getLocation());
                                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                }
                            } else {
                                holder.frameView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.fulfilled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.requestFulfilled.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                /*------------- Set current user card as visible -----------------*/
                                holder.userEmail.setText(AuthUserEmail);
                                holder.bloodGroup.setText(model.getBloodGroup());
                                holder.dateOfRequirement.setText(model.getDate());
                                holder.Location.setText(model.getLocation());
                                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            }

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                } else if (model.getUser().equals(null)) {
                    holder.userEmail.setText("You have not posted any request");
                } else {
                    holder.frameView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                /*  Fulfilled and Delete button Functionality  */
                holder.fulfilled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
                        response.put("Fulfilled", "yes");

                        /*-----------------Remove Responses------------------*/

                        dbRefForResp.removeValue();
                        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                        /*-----------------Update and insert child with fulfilled status as yes------------------*/
                        dbRefForReq.child(String.valueOf(("Request " + finalPosition))).child("Fulfillment").setValue(response).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(yourRequestActivity.this, "Request fulfillment status posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        holder.fulfilled.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.requestFulfilled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public contentHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_request_card, viewGroup, false);
                contentHolder contentViewHolder = new contentHolder(view);
                return contentViewHolder;
            }
        };
        cardView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }


    public class contentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userEmail, bloodGroup, dateOfRequirement, Location, requestFulfilled;
        Button fulfilled;
        FrameLayout frameView;

        public contentHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RemailView);
            bloodGroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RbloodView);
            dateOfRequirement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RdateView);
            Location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RlocationView);

            requestFulfilled = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fulfilledTextMessage);
            frameView = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardFrame);
            fulfilled = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Requestfulfilled);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove the blank space which occurs while visibility is set to GONE, as shown in the snapshot below.

[Image of empty space on removing top card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo3ZH.jpg)

[Image before setting visibility GONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9yDW.jpg)

Comment: Show the image when u havent set visibility to gone pls.

Comment: Try formatting your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K instead of ```. I already formatted it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecyclerView` takes space even if visibility is set to gone. It still takes space because there are items that `RecyclerView` wants to display. Although you can fix this by removing the items `RecyclerView` wants to show. It would take a lot of memory if you want show that `RecyclerView` again because you still have to add the items back. What I would recommend is to wrap your `RecyclerView` with a layout eg. `LinearLayout` and set that layout's visibility to gone.

Try doing this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--  Place your RecyclerView here -->
    <!--  change visibility of container view -->

</LinearLayout>
```

*Edit: You didn't explain it well. I get what you want now. You simply have to remove the item from your `RecyclerView` list. The best way to do this is by using `DiffUtil`. This a great tutorial online showing how you can implement it in Java. https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/room-viewmodel-livedata-recyclerview-mvvm/part-1-introduction

Comment: I tried your way, i.e to wrap recyclerview with linearlayout, when I put android:layout_height="wrap_content" it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Deepak wdym? You want to remove empty space. It really won't show anything

Comment: because in this example there is only one card on top, if there are multiple cards on top then it will show lot of empty space on top.

Comment: @Deepak Sorry, I don't really get what you want to achieve. Can you explain it further? I really dont get it since you said that if there are multiple cards on top, it will show empty space on top. You want to remove the empty space on top right? Then, we have to set visibility of the layout to gone.

Comment: After setting the visibility to GONE I am getting empty space there, which I want to remove.

Comment: @Deepak I get it now. You want to display the card and want to remove one card. You simply have to remove the item from your list then. I update the answer

Comment: I've used pojo method and not stored data in list that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the object from the list if its user is not equal to AuthUserEmail and notify your adapter.

**NO NEED TO MAKE VISBILITY GONE OF THE HOLDER VIEW**

Comment: can you please tell me this in the form of code? Need help to remove the object

Comment: Please add complete adapter code. I will edit the code

Comment: Hey, Ive added the complete code, now can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

Cover your RecyclerView with a FrameLayout and then set your visibility over there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If this doesnt works then:

Cover your Cardview which is the layout that you designed for your Recyclerview with a FrameLayout. Anyone of them will surely work out for you.

Comment: I have to give an id to frame and then set that id as visible in my class right?

Comment: Just try to make this change....dont do anything else changes. Nd check first. Is it working or not.

Comment: but then it wont show anything :/ you mean to remove the setvisibility(GONE) part? or remove both setvisibility(VISIBLE) as well as setvisibility(GONE) ?

Comment: ok, give the framelayout an id. Then using the position of the item that you want to hide, call visibility(gone) on the framelayout object.

Comment: HEY, thanks a lot it worked, I just used the FrameLayout outside the cardView.

Comment: My pleasure....pls upvote my ans and mark it as accepted so that others may know the solution for it.

Comment: Hey sorry bruh, it didn't work, i thought it worked but after running on device/emulator it didn't work